# Yelp Academic Dataset

Tags: medical, machine-learning

I heard about the Yelp Dataset, I did not download it yet, I just need to know if the reviews about a specific service on this dataset are identified by the unique id of the person who wrote the review?

Comment: what yelp dataset? what is preventing you from downloading it and checking this yourself?

Comment: Thank you Albert for your feedback, it is a huge dataset (more than 9 Gb) and in json format, that is why i would like to hear from the persons already worked with the Yelp Dataset..